# Image brightness correction using open cv python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, orb

I'm involved in a computer vision project wherein I need to detect the key features and align those images with the keypoints detected. This I could able to perform somehow. But the latter I need to stitch some part of the second photo to the first. While doing this process, there is a difference in brightness/colour difference in the portion where the image is stitched. (Example photo is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJX27.jpg)). I would very happy If someone could give a solution to minimise the difference. I have tried averaging with nearby pixel value, gaussian blur, but still, the difference is prominent.
Code I used for blurring and filter is as follows,

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
dst = cv2.filter2D(final,-1,kernel)
dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst,(5,5),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are a number of deep learning based color transfer approaches, based on your example, I would suggest first trying basic/classical methods. First, try basic [gamma/brightness adjustment](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html) techniques before you do the matching. If that isn't satisfactory,  [this classical color transfer method](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eturkel/imagepapers/ColorTransfer.pdf) should give decent results (again, based on your example). It works by converting the images from RGB to the lαβ (which has the particularity of minimizing the correlation between channels), computing statistics (mean, std) in that color space for both source and target images and by finally forcing the source distribution on the target image. There are a lot of implementations of it available if you do a quick search.